# Get PHP page response in controller in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, response

in symfony ,

i have one page , gives some string .

**page url** :

```
 "localhost/project/rest1.php"   ==>this page gives "444-556-666".
```

now i want to call this page in controller and get that string in some variable.

```
 /**
 * @Route("/ws/checkout/{param}",defaults = {"param"=""},requirements={"param"=".+"})
 * @Template()
 */
 public function checkoutAction($param){

       **//  want that php page response here**
 }
```

Comment: use `include` in your controller.

Comment: how can i use include in Controller ?

Comment: `include __DIR__.'YOUR_FILE_PATH';` at the top of your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller to the following

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function checkoutAction($param, Request $request){
    $response = file_get_contents($request->getHost() . '/project/rest1.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `file_get_contents()`

```
$output = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/project/rest1.php");
```

Comment: Thanks , #Jimish Gamit